# Create a Array from HashMap in Java

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I want to create a Array of String from a Hashmap In java?

My **HashMap** is like this

```
HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 param.put("A", "2");
                 param.put("B", "3");
                 param.put("C", "2");
```

I want to create a **Array** of String like this .

```
String[] list = {"A 1", "A 2","B 1","B 2","B 3","C 1","C 2"};
```

Edit:

> relationship between input and out put. If key A's value is 2 out put
>   should contains A 1 and A 2 like wise if key B's value is 3 out put should
>   contains B 1 B 2 B3 and so on.

What i have done is

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
        param.put("A", "2");
        param.put("B", "3");
        param.put("C", "2");

        String[] list = new String[param.size()];
        int i = 0;
        int a= Integer.parseInt(param.get("A"));
        for (int j = 1;j<= a;j++) {
            list[i] = ("a" +j);
            System.out.println(list[i]);
            i++;

        }

    }
```

I am new In Java .Please help to how could i do this .Thanks

Comment: Ok,what you have tried so far ??

Comment: Start with `for (String key : param.keys()) {...}` and see where it takes you...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Most likely you can avoid needing to create this array at all unless this is homework.

Comment: @MadProgrammer `for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: param.entrySet())` might be more efficient.

Comment: actaully i have to create a listview in Android.of for that i need a array and i am getting my data in the form of hashmap

Comment: can u please provide my some sample code for this

Comment: @Gaurav what is the relationship of these input and output....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
    param.put("A", "2");
    param.put("B", "3");
    param.put("C", "2");

    String[] list = new String[7];// It is better to use List other than an array
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : param.entrySet()) {
        int lim=Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue());
       for(int j=0;j<lim;j++){
          list[i]=entry.getKey()+" "+String.valueOf(j+1);
           i++;
       }
    }
```

If you really want to use array here. You can try following way

```
  HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
    param.put("A", "2");
    param.put("B", "3");
    param.put("C", "2");
    int sum=0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : param.entrySet()) {
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue());
    }
    String[] list = new String[sum];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : param.entrySet()) {
        int lim=Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue());
       for(int j=0;j<lim;j++){
          list[i]=entry.getKey()+" "+String.valueOf(j+1);
           i++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: see if the value of A is 2 then in the array it will be like A 1,A 2 so on..if A is 3 then A 1,A 2,A 3 same as for every key that i have in HashMAp

Comment: @Gaurav check my solution. Your question doesn't explain this. now i got your point. I will vote for reopen this question. It is better to use `List` other than an `array`

Comment: actually i have to return the array same i have posted in the question.because i have to populate this in a listview in android.Please suggest how can i do this

Comment: i need a array of string

Comment: @Gaurav so you have it, check my second solution after these steps `String[] list= = {"A 1", "A 2","B 1","B 2","B 3","C 1","C 2"};`. So ??

Comment: @Gaurav after those steps `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(list))` out put `[A 1, A 2, B 1, B 2, B 3, C 1, C 2]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35571/discussion-between-ruchira-and-gaurav)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, something like:

```
String[] list = new String[param.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : param.entrySet()) {
    list[i] = entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue();
    ++i;
}
assert i == list.length;
Arrays.sort(list);
```

I think however that you want a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`.

---

Why not:

```
SortedSet<String> param;

void putParam(String key, String addableValue) {
    param.add(key + " " + addableValue);
}

putParam("A". "1");
putParam("B", "1");
putParam("A". "2");
putParam("B", "1");

String[] list = param.toArray(new String[param.size()]);
// [ "A 1", "A 2", "B 1" ]
```

For generic typing, toArray needs an array object of String. Giving that array the correct size, will reuse that array as return value, `list`.

Comment: i want the output as String[] list = {"A 1", "A 2","B 1","B 2","B 3","C 1","C 2"};

Comment: @Gaurav tell me what is the relationship with input and out put?

Answer (score 0):

Basic algorithm should be:

> For each key in the map (use param.entrySet())
>   Iterate `value` number of times and push
>   into the array/list.